# How to add pause on Typed.js rendering the strings

Tags: javascript, typed.js

I am working on the below code. How can I add a pause before start of typing each element? As you can see in this demo Typed.js is rendering new element exactly after the  back clean finishes, I want to pause there for a few and then start new elements typing.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      Typed.new('.type', {
        strings: ["neighbor", "family", "team", "community"],
        stringsElement: null,
        // typing speed
        typeSpeed: 60,
        // time before typing starts
        startDelay: 600,
        // backspacing speed
        backSpeed: 20,
        // time before backspacing
        backDelay: 500,
        // loop
        loop: true,
        // false = infinite
        loopCount: false,
        // show cursor
        showCursor: false,
        // character for cursor
        cursorChar: "|",
        // attribute to type (null == text)
        attr: null,
        // either html or text
        contentType: 'html',
      });
  });
```

```css
.center {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background:#f7f7f7;
}

span {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 25px;
}
span.type {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
span.type::after {
  content: "|";
  display: inline;
  animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}

/*Removes cursor that comes with typed.js*/
.typed-cursor {
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

/*Custom cursor animation*/
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.7/typed.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
    <div class="text">
        <span>Love your </span><span class="type"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A quick reminder that your posts have a needy, begging tone, and this may put readers off helping you. If you can stick to technical writing, and assume that you will be doing the bulk of the work if you receive an answer, that is a good approach for using Stack Overflow generally.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the value of 'backDelay' to the number of milliseconds you want the typed text to be on screen.